# Which resource qualifier to use for the android layout screen?

Tags: java, android, mobile, layout, qualifiers

I am a beginner in android and is going to finish my first app, but encountering a problem that my screen layout does not fits all screen sizes,currently I have created different layouts for different screen sizes using 'size' resource qualifier. Should I use 'density' qualifier also along with size?
or ratio qualifier.I am having too much confusion. Please anybody reading this help me out.
My app will be focusing only mobile phones not any other device.
Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this android sdk from screen density pixel works for all the screen sizes with percentage of the screen ratio its a life saver

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: hey there..thanx for replying but how to use it?